# Highlight a cell when information in that cell's row is duplicate in 2 of it's columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, highlighting

I'm looking for a conditional formatting rule that would highlight a cell if data in that cell's row is duplicated in more than one column. Specifically for this sheet, I want the cell in column B to highlight if the data in column A AND column B are duplicated anywhere else in those columns.

Here is an example to illustrate what I would want the rule to do - the borders are for emphasis in the example, I only need the highlighting to work.

[image: Example]

I have hit a wall trying to do this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1)>1`

Answer (score 0):

Select the Range B1:B9, go to Home- Conditional Formatting- New rule- Use a formula to determine which cells to format- enter the formula and set the cell format:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1&B1=$A$1:$A$9&$B$1:$B$9)*1)>1
```

[image]